# How to emulate clean mac environment to test .app

Tags: macos, qt

I created the .app with Qt application that I'd like to distribute. It works fine on my developer machine and now I want to test it on clean mac system to check if all dependencies bundled and it works correctly. But I don't have another clean mac.
Is there a way to emulate clean environment on dev machine to check the .app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install macOS on a **virtual machine**, using *Parallels* or *VMware Fusion*.

This can be useful to ensure your app is deployed correctly, with all the dependencies in the right place.

However, keep in mind that the VM **won't support accelerate graphics**, so if your app is using OpenGL, you will not be able to test it in this kind of environment.

Comment: Thanks.
Found this article useful for installing to Parallels - https://willhaley.com/blog/macos-virtual-machine-mac/